# How to set up this union in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that returns one of a handful of possible JSX elements. Each element has their own defined typescript props.

```
const Thing1 = (props) => <div>Thing 1</div> 
const Thing2 = (props) => <div>Thing 2</div> 

type Thing1Props = {
  one: string;
  two: string;
}

type Thing2Props = {
  three: string;
  four: string;
}

const elementList: { name: string; elm: (props: ElementList) => JSX.Element }[] = [
  { name: 'thing1', elm: (props: Thing1Props) => <Thing1 {...props} /> },
  { name: 'thing2', elm: (props: Thing2Props) => <Thing2 {...props} /> },
];

export type ElementList = Thing1Props | Thing2Props;
```

I'm getting an error from typescript that reads:

```
TS2322: Type '(props: { one: string; two: string;}) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type '(props: ElementList) => Element'.   
Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.     
Type 'ElementList' is not assignable to type '{ one: string; two: string; }'.       
Type '{ three: string; four: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ one: string; two: string; }': one, two
```

Typescript seems to be viewing ElementList as an AND instead of an OR. Not sure what to change here. I'm guessing because it doesn't know which element I'm calling upon it can't define the types.

Here's the issue in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCrQgDsBneAFQAtg6BzARjgF44ACjA4wDAFxw2HHgAVRDAJT8AfHAA8AE2AA3FdK5xu6gPTa9cGvSZT2XAEz8hIiGMkHO9+a6WqN5-TtOOHtTAMtqShgATzAkWxlubzEnAG8qODh6JEkmKBkKSkyYAHcIXJh8rkKAXyoqGLiEh2SGNIy4GFYiHLg8go7MCABXKAqqzlr6ylpGeCQAGyQQJDoYABlgJklUuDoUFfGCuEWQSWEFSQBRJZW1zaZlPjUAKQBlAA0AOhvl1fgagBtAC6TkBHV2+0OBC6iXwABoTgszs5Ls05Aonmp1B5eKkvgSXGIanATGoavCIXsDr18LCHAikSiLj53EEvJi-Dj2XB8YSFCSyXAKVRgYUqEgAB6QWCdWLxX53DZbeACXGtOAAH3RHJ84pm1ggSy+CwgnEEiz+9xVilIQA)

Comment: Can you create a code sandbox of your issue. Some parts of your code seem to be missing, I cannot see the statement that would cause the error

Comment: Hrmmm... strange I can't get codesandbox to recreate the error. It only appears in my application. I've recreated the issue faithfully to my problem, not sure why I don't get the same response from codesandbox.

Comment: Oh, it appears in typescript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCrQgDsBneAFQAtg6BzARjgF44ACjA4wDAFxw2HHgAVRDAJT8AfHAA8AE2AA3FdK5xu6gPTa9cGvSZT2XAEz8hIiGMkHO9+a6WqN5-TtOOHtTAMtqShgATzAkWxlubzEnAG8qODh6JEkmKBkKSkyYAHcIXJh8rkKAXyoqGLiEh2SGNIy4GFYiHLg8go7MCABXKAqqzlr6ylpGeCQAGyQQJDoYABlgJklUuDoUFfGCuEWQSWEFSQBRJZW1zaZlPjUAKQBlAA0AOhvl1fgagBtAC6TkBHV2+0OBC6iXwABoTgszs5Ls05Aonmp1B5eKkvgSXGIanATGoavCIXsDr18LCHAikSiLj53EEvJi-Dj2XB8YSFCSyXAKVRgYUqEgAB6QWCdWLxX53DZbeACXGtOAAH3RHJ84pm1ggSy+CwgnEEiz+9xVilIQA

Comment: `(props: ElementList) => JSX.Element` is not the right type, since that sort of function needs to accept any argument of type `ElementList`; functions can't choose to accept *narrower* types than they are declared to; that would be like a dog groomer that turns you away because your dog is not a golden retriever.  You need to represent the correlation between the `name` field and the argument to `elm` for this to work... perhaps like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKy3DN); does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That works, thanks! If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the type `{ name: string; elm: (props: ElementList) => JSX.Element }` is `elm` needs to be a function that accepts any possible argument of type `ElementList`.  Assuming you have [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) enabled (and you should), then TypeScript will not allow a function of this type to choose to only accept *some* arguments of type `ElementList`.  Functions may not safely *narrow* their input types.  But they can *widen* them; a function of type `(props: ElementList | string) => JSX.Element` would be acceptable there, since if it accepts `ElementList | string` then it definitely accepts `ElementList`.  It is said that *functions are [contravariant](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) in their argument types*; a specific instance of a function type can widen but not narrow its argument types.  So this isn't the type you want.

Instead it seems that you want to represent the correlation between the `name` property and the type of the `props` parameter of `elm`.  So the actual type you want looks like:

```
type Elem = {
    name: "thing1";
    elm: (props: Thing1Props) => JSX.Element;
} | {
    name: "thing2";
    elm: (props: Thing2Props) => JSX.Element;
};

const elementList: Elem[] = [
  { name: 'thing1', elm: (props: Thing1Props) => <Thing1 {...props} /> },
  { name: 'thing2', elm: (props: Thing2Props) => <Thing2 {...props} /> },
]; // okay
```

That is, instead of having `props` be a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), you want the entire object to be a union type.  In fact, this `Elem` type is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), where you can check the `name` property to see which `props` it needs:

```
function processElem(elem: Elem) {
  switch (elem.name) {
    case "thing1": return elem.elm({ one: "", two: "" });
    case "thing2": return elem.elm({ three: "", four: "" });
  }
}
```

---

You *could* write that `Elem` type out by hand, but this could be tedious if you have a lot of `Thing`s. Instead you could start with a mapping interface like

```
interface ThingPropMap {
  thing1: Thing1Props,
  thing2: Thing2Props
}
```

to represent the correlation, and then have the compiler *evaluate* `Elem` like

```
type Elem = { [K in keyof ThingPropMap]:
  { name: K, elm: (props: ThingPropMap[K]) => JSX.Element }
}[keyof ThingPropMap]
```

, which is a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  A distributive object type is of the form `{[K in X]: F<K>}[X]` where `X` is some keylike type or union of keylike types, and where `F<K>` is some type function that operates on a keylike type.  By immediately [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), you end up getting the union of `F<K>` for every `K` in `X`.  So if `X` is `K1 | K2 | K3`, then the distributive object type is `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3>`.

So the `Elem` definition then computes the union of `{ name: K, elm: (props: ThingPropMap[K]) => JSX.Element }` for every `K` in `keyof ThingPropMap`.

Again, this is not necessary if you're willing to write out the discriminated union by hand.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4AVAC2BoHMBGOAXjgAowOMHQBccFmy4AFYXQCUvAHxwAPABNgANyWSOcTqoD0mnVVoMJrDgCZeAoRBHi97G7KcLla07uvs4G2NfShgATzAkKylODxF7AG9yODhaJHEGKCkKFJgAdwgMmCyOCgBfUIio13c5ROS4GGYidLhM7IbMCABXKCKS9nLKNhgkKEx0av84gFkUMDgk3P9OFxW4ugAaBqapGzW9jfIK8nDIuABRABskPD4EuABtAGk4NjgAayQwiExojlm8wAuqIGg8aCgQK1nps4EgriBxII5AcAcI5mAXkDFDwVAApADKAA0AHTXW5IGjwCplR5fH5-VyAsBAyhGABUjSqlxud0WDRSEKh4gARLsOJwRTkUnCEUjHM5-jI5Dj8cSybzKTBynAAD78mVwIWtMX+GxSgWyxEOFFK2qeVVwQmk8lQqk69lGSiYbo0DDAWhwRxoJB0Oiu-jw27iV2KJZtPLAGBoZgCKMgEnGuOWtAoOhRU0xEXiIgwXo0WW3EnwkD8B5pUUi2H5QpwEUiuBleTSlK5-Nt8VuYtwUvlysZmt1xrNJAmptwLq9Rud7sNGmUaj0eDprUAGWADBjvMeQPsjzBRshrXwg84+FhNflttcsRV3lUL8WJO-CroZTgRgqGU2wpOCV7iDeZr3laT6eKibgbI6H5ml+P5yP+gGdtsQIUOQSAAB6QLAXLnK6e4HvAfBMui8x0t8vxKsyp7kEAA)